# Best block explorer for windows with btc core synched

Tags: blockexplorer

I have btc core synched on my windows 10 pc. What would be the best block explorer software to use to locally search the blockchain? Id prefer to stay on windows, but if there is absolutely no option I can switch to linux.

Comment: Your available options will largely depend on whether you use Bitcoin Core in pruned mode (in which case you won't have much to explore) or you have the full blockchain stored locally (then you can explore it with some limitations), and whether you're ready to dedicate another 50-100 GB of disk space for your block explorer to index the blockchain (then you can do pretty much anything).

Comment: Try [NBXplorer](https://github.com/dgarage/NBXplorer/)